# deque iterator not dereferencable error in thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl

I've written a thread pool using SDL2's threading library, which uses the following thread function:

```
int threadFunc(void * pData)
{
    ThreadData* data = (ThreadData*)pData;
    SDLTaskManager* pool = data->pool;
    Task* task = nullptr;
    while (true)
    {
        SDL_LockMutex(pool->getMutex());
        while (!pool->isRunning() && !pool->hasTasks())
        {
            SDL_CondWait(pool->getCondition(), pool->getMutex());
        }
        if (pool->shuttingDown())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        task = pool->getNextTask(); //SDL_CondWait relocks mutex, so this *should* be thread safe.
        if (task != nullptr)
        {
            pool->notifyThreadWorking(true);
            data->taskCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            pool->stop();
            SDL_UnlockMutex(pool->getMutex());
            continue;
        }
        SDL_UnlockMutex(pool->getMutex());
        task->execute();
        SDL_LockMutex(pool->getMutex());
        pool->notifyThreadWorking(false);
        pool->addCompleteTask(task);
        SDL_UnlockMutex(pool->getMutex());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the debug assertation error "Deque iterator is not dereferencable", when pool->getNextTask() is called. I've checked the contents of the deque which the pool maintains via the call stack and found that it's definitely not empty when this function is called.

The function code is as follows:

```
Task * SDLTaskManager::getNextTask()
{
    Task* t = nullptr;
    if (!mCurrentTasks.empty())
    {   
        t = mCurrentTasks.front();  //this part is causing the error
        mCurrentTasks.pop_front();  //this is a std::deque<Task*>
    }
    return t;
}
```

The deque has valid data in it, so I'm at a loss as to what is causing the problem.

Comment: One thing strikes me as probably wrong: You have to lock the mutex first and then wait on the condition variable, which will release the lock automatically. Also, checking if there are tasks and then handling them without a lock doesn't work. Retrieving the task may happen some unspecified time later, after other threads may already have handled the task. Lastly, without a minimal but complete example, your question is considered off-topic. For demonstration, consider you talk about a deque iterator but there's no deque in sight anywhere...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I thought that condition variables require you to already hold the lock on the mutex before performing operations?

Comment: If I'm running that function in multiple threads, wouldn't locking the mutex before calling SDL_CondWait create a deadlock situation?

Comment: Not sure, what does the documentation say? What have your attempts shown? What does your understanding of the condition variable give as answer here?

Comment: According to the documentation, if a mutex is locked, other threads seeking to lock the same mutex are blocked, until the mutex is again unlocked

Using SDL_CondWait, unlocks the mutex then waits for a signal. Upon receiving the signal, the mutex is once again locked, before continuing. I've updated the code to reflect this information.

The problem with the debug assertation failure persists, with the code getting to  t = mCurrentTasks.front(), and crashing, stating the deque iterator is not dereferencable. Once again, examining the contents of the deque confims a non empty deque status.

Comment: Good that you found that, you're making progress. Now, consider the last part of my initial comment. Your question remains off-topic, and that is for good reason, too.

Comment: I'm going to rework my question, as I don't think this is due to the deque itself and more due to thread synchronisation issues, so feel free to close this one.